# How can make this code interact with other programs?

Tags: python, passwords

So I have made a code that is sort of a brute force password guesser that is made to guess a 3 letter password.

I know this code is not correct because the `while` statement is obviously wrong so how could I fix that?

Also how could I make this code interact with other programs?

For example:

Winrar has some files that need a 3 word password and has an enter screen where you type the password.  How could I make this my code interact or 'type' within that password enter box?

```
import random
import string

while password != correct: 
    letter 1 = random.choice(string.letters)
    letter 2 = random.choice(string.letters)
    letter 3 = random.choice(string.letters)
    word = '%s%s%s'%(letter1, letter2, letter3) 
    if word == password:
        print "The code is %s"%(word) 
    else:
        break;
```

Comment: You say: 'I know obviiously this code is not correct and will not work right because the while statement is obviously wrong '. Please point out what exactly is wrong before anyone can jump into answering your question

Comment: Sorry about that @GodMan I meant the actual statement of "while password != correct" is not a correct statement because "correct" is not a syntax of python. With that said, I am just wondering how I could rewrite it to where it would work. Like to where the password would print once it is the correct one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a terrible way to go about this, but....

```
import random
import string

while True:
    # Do it until the `if` block says it's right, then break.
    word = ''.join([random.choice(string.letters) for _ in range(3)])
    if word == password:
        print "The code is %s" % (word)
        break
```

EDIT: `''.join([random.choice(string.letters) for _ in range(3)])` explained, as per your request in the comments.

`[x for x in list_of_xs]` is a list comprehension. You can do transformations on the resultant item (for example, all perfect squares from roots 1-10 is `[x**2 for x in range(1,11)]` or more simply `[x**2 for x in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] ]`. There's lots of info out there on this, and tons of canonical SO answers.

`random.choice(string.letters)` you already use, so that much you get. `''.join` is using the `str.join` command, which combines an iterable of strings into one string, using the `str` as a separator. `", ".join(["Eggs","Cheese","Bread","Milk"])` results in `"Eggs, Cheese, Bread, Milk"`. In this case I'm using an empty string to combine.

Basically I'm building a list of three `random.choice(string.letters)` (the `_` isn't anything special, it's just notation for the next programmer that comes along that this variable isn't necessary. `[do_something for _ in range(x)]` is a common idiom for a list of `do_something`s `x` long), then combining them together with an empty string in between them (in other words, NOTHING in between them)

Maybe

```
import random
import string

while word != password:
    # do the same stuff
```

But honestly what you're trying to do is:

```
import itertools as it
for attempt in (''.join(combo) for combo in it.combinations(string.letters,3)):
    if attempt == password:
        print "success:",attempt
else:
    print "failure"
```

To pre-empt your question, `itertools` (which I imported as `it`) has a method `combinations` that returns all of the unique combinations of the iterable you hand it of the sequence length `r`. The notation is `itertools.combinations(iterable,r)`. It returns a list of tuples, which then need to be combined in the same way I did above.

The only failing of THIS method is that it can't catch passwords like `"aaa"`. Any repeated characters won't show up in `combinations`.

As far as your title: "How can I make this code interact with other programs" is too broad for this question. It's not a good fit unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you but just out of curousity could you explain to me how this code is "Read through"? Like what does the "word = ''.join([random.choice(string.letters) for _ in range(3)])" thing do? And why is the code a terrible way?

Comment: Hmmm ok the "itertools" is a new thing to me but I think I am kind of getting the gist of things. But tell me if I am understanding this correctly. The "word = ''.join([random.choice(string.letters) for _ in range(3)])" is basically saying; take 3 random letters and adjoin them and label these 3 random adjoined letters as a variable called "Word"? Am I right?

Comment: If you use `combinations_with_replacement` instead of `combinations` you'll get `aaa`